# Bash command works in terminal but not in script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to run a C executable(rtklib) with some parameters.  The same command seems to work fine in terminal but when I run it in a sh file, the executable throws error.

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# path to CUI executables
convbindir="/home/odroid/gitLibs/RTKLIB-master/app/convbin/gcc"
rnx2rtkpdir="/home/odroid/gitLibs/RTKLIB-master/app/rnx2rtkp/gcc"

datafiledir="/home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles"

basedir="$datafiledir/base*/"


cd $rnx2rtkpdir



# Do post process from each base to rover (should be 2)
for roverdir in $datafiledir/rover*/; do
    #echo "$roverdir" # absolute path to rover folder i.e. /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/rover2/ 
    #echo "basedir = $basedir" 

    rovernum="${roverdir: -2:-1}"
    #echo "$rovernum"   
    ls
    #echo "****************"
    echo "executing: $ ./rnx2rtkp -k optsEmlid.conf -o "$roverdir"rover"$rovernum".pos "$roverdir"*.obs "$basedir"*.obs "$basedir"*.nav"
    ./rnx2rtkp -k optsEmlid.conf -o "$roverdir"rover"$rovernum".pos "$roverdir"*.obs "$basedir"*.obs "$basedir"*.nav
    #echo "****************"
done
```

output (no nav datanav data error):

```
odroid@odroid:~/bashExample$ ./autopostprocess.sh 
ephemeris.o  makefile    opts4.conf  ppp_ar.o   rnx2rtkp    rtcm.o
geoid.o      options.o   optsEmlid.conf  ppp.o      rnx2rtkp.o  rtkcmn.o
gpsdata      opts1.conf  out.pos     preceph.o  rtcm2.o rtkpos.o
ionex.o      opts2.conf  pntpos.o    qzslex.o   rtcm3e.o    sbas.o
lambda.o     opts3.conf  postpos.o   rinex.o    rtcm3.o solution.o
executing: $ ./rnx2rtkp -k optsEmlid.conf -o /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/rover2/rover2.pos /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/rover2/*.obs /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/base*/*.obs /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/base*/*.nav
invalid option value pos1-snrmask (optsEmlid.conf:7)
no nav datanav data
ephemeris.o  makefile    opts4.conf      ppp_ar.o   rnx2rtkp    rtcm.o
geoid.o      options.o   optsEmlid.conf  ppp.o      rnx2rtkp.o  rtkcmn.o
gpsdata      opts1.conf  out.pos     preceph.o  rtcm2.o rtkpos.o
ionex.o      opts2.conf  pntpos.o    qzslex.o   rtcm3e.o    sbas.o
lambda.o     opts3.conf  postpos.o   rinex.o    rtcm3.o solution.o
executing: $ ./rnx2rtkp -k optsEmlid.conf -o /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/rover3/rover3.pos /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/rover3/*.obs /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/base*/*.obs /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/base*/*.nav
invalid option value pos1-snrmask (optsEmlid.conf:7)
no nav datanav data
```

executing on terminal manually(I ctr+c to quit early, note that i copy pasted the exact command i printed out in my script i.e. the text after executing: $)):

```
odroid@odroid:~/gitLibs/RTKLIB-master/app/rnx2rtkp/gcc$ ./rnx2rtkp -k optsEmlid.conf -o /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/rover2/rover2.pos /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/rover2/*.obs /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/base*/*.obs /home/odroid/bashExample/datafiles/base*/*.nav
invalid option value pos1-snrmask (optsEmlid.conf:7)
^Cocessing : 2018/01/03 21:05:47 Q=0
odroid@odroid:~/gitLibs/RTKLIB-master/app/rnx2rtkp/gcc$
```

Comment: When you quote an expansion, that prevents globs from being expanded.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you clarify more in an answer? im new to bash thanks.

Comment: How many distinct directories do you expect `"$datafiledir"/base*/` to match? If there's only one, then make it `basedir=( "$datafiledir"/base*/ )`

Comment: Instead of using `echo` to represent what a command will do when run, instead use `bash -x your-script`.

Comment: As a simplified example of *why* using `echo` this way is faulty, compare `printf '%s\n' "hello world"` to the output of `echo printf '%s\n' "hello world"`.

Comment: Or, more directly on-point, consider the difference between output of running `echo '*'` and the output of running the command emitted by `echo echo '*'`.

Comment: ...which is to say: when you put the `*` inside quotes, that prevents expansion and makes it literal, so after running `basedir='whatever*'`, `"$basedir"*.nav` is expanding `*.nav` inside a directory that has a literal `*` character in its name, hence your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `echo` does not represent whether content is quoted, although quotes matter greatly in terms of how a command is interpreted.

The safe way to do this is to expand your glob into an array, and then validate the array's contents to check whether the glob expanded to exactly one item (as you expect it to). That may look something like the following:

```
shopt -s nullglob
base_inputs=( "$datafiledir"/base*/*.{obs,nav} )

for roverdir in "$datafiledir"/rover*/; do
  roverdir=${roverdir%/}; rovernum=${roverdir##*/rover}
  ./rnx2rtkp \
    -k optsEmlid.conf \
    -o "${roverdir}/rover${rovernum}.pos" \
    "$roverdir"/*.obs \
    "${base_inputs[@]}"
done
```

Comment: I assumed he wanted to process all the matching files in all directories that match `$basedir`.

Comment: Could be. It'd be helpful if we had a better specification.

Comment: there is 1 base directory but I dont know the name of it except it has the word "base" in the name

Comment: Ahh -- then my [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48086333/1) was appropriate (as it focused on safely validating that assumption).

Comment: Where are you checking that the glob expanded to exactly one in your answer?

Comment: @bakalolo, the original version -- follow the link I gave you above -- made that explicit. The new version expands the glob inside all `base*` directories that exist, even if that number is 0 (due to the use of the `nullglob` flag).

Comment: @bakalolo, ...because both versions answer the question as it was asked, I'm selecting the version to leave here in such a manner as to be as useful as possible to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're quoting `$basedir` when you execute the command, so it's not expanding the `*` wildcard, and looking for a directory literally named `base*`. Change to:

```
    ./rnx2rtkp -k optsEmlid.conf -o "$roverdir"rover"$rovernum".pos "$roverdir"*.obs $basedir*.obs $basedir*.nav
```

However, this is problematic because it won't work if any of the directories in `$basedir` have spaces in their names, since word splitting is also done.

Comment: I agree that this fixes the immediate problem, but I disagree -- strongly -- that it's an appropriate practice to teach. Someone following the advice given here will never be able to use filenames with spaces.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of agree. If you can show a better way, please post an answer.